# Dynamic Conditional Multi-Select Combo Boxes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am making a form with two multi-select combo boxes: Category and Subcategory. I would like to have the Subcategory box update with all relevant values for each selected option in the Category box. My SubCategory table is set up with each SubCategory having a Category it belongs to.

If I select only a single Category, the SubCategory options display correctly. However, if I select multiple Categories, I only see the SubCategory options pertaining to the first Category in the list. If I uncheck the first Category, the SubCategory options shown will be those of the second Category, and so on.

```
Private Sub CategoryCombo_AfterUpdate()

  Dim AppsArray() As String

  Dim length As Integer, counter As Integer

  With SubCombo

    If IsNull(Me!Category) Then

      .RowSource = ""

    Else

      AppsArray() = Split(Me!Category, ",")

      .RowSource = "SELECT [SubCategory].[SubCategory] " & _

                   "FROM [SubCategory] " & _

                   "WHERE ([SubCategory].[Category]='" & AppsArray(0) & "')"

    length = UBound(AppsArray) - LBound(AppsArray) + 1

     For counter = 1 To length - 1

        .RowSource = .RowSource & " OR ([SubCategory].[Category]='" & AppsArray(counter) & "')"

     Next
     .RowSource = .RowSource & " ORDER BY [SubCategory].[Category];"

    End If

    MsgBox SubCombo.RowSource

    Call .Requery

  End With

End Sub
```

The MsgBox output shows

> "SELECT [SubCategory].[SubCategory] FROM [SubCategory] WHERE
>   ([SubCategory].[Category]='Category1') OR
>   ([SubCategory].[Category]='Category2') OR
>   ([SubCategory].[Category]='Category3') ORDER BY
>   [SubCategory].[Category]

Which is what I had intended, but only Category1's SubCategory options are being shown.

Comment: I am confused. A multi-select combobox is only available when bound to a multi-value field. MVF is not a CSV so Split() should not work. MVF stores pointers to hidden dependent table. Even if field did store CSV, `OR` criteria would not work because CSV is a single string of characters, not multiple discreet values - would have to use `LIKE` with wildcard.

Comment: I'm grabbing the output of the combo box, which is a string with each category separated by commas - that's what I'm splitting. I'm using those to build an SQL statement for the RowSource property, which is where the ORs are being applied, not to the individual split strings themselves. When I manually type in the output code into the RowSource Query Builder, it works, so I know the query syntax is correct. It's only the dynamic VBA code that is not working properly.

Comment: I am still confused. So not really multi-select combobox? No MVF in table design? Edit question to show sample data as tables (not images). I still say `OR` criteria should not work against a CSV value, manually typed or VBA, unless LIKE and wildcard are used.